# WebServiceSecurity Reference. What is it?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I inherited a project that includes a reference to "WebServiceSecurity". What is this dll? Is it a .NET assembly?

And additionally, where is is located in my system?

Here is a screen shot of the relevant section of the Solution Explorer from VS.

[image]

TIA

Comment: It looks to be from the .NET 2.0 Framework.  Do you have that installed?

Comment: @jonnyGold: Yes I do have it installed. What is the dll file called? Is it simply WebServiceSecurity.dll? I can't find that file.

Comment: Delete that reference and see if any code misses it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I like your style, but unfortunately it is referenced.

Comment: And, which code references it? That was the other half of my question.

Comment: the properties on the reference will tell you what the full path to the file "should" be, if it were present. that may help identify it.

Comment: WebServiceSecurity.dll _should_ be in the GAC if it is part of the 2.0 Framework, no?

Comment: It is not part of .NET. It may be part of the obsolete WSE software.

Answer (score 1):

It ends up not being a .NET assembly, but part of a third-party CRM vendor (Pivotal).